# Power supply from PCI connector pin B25 or B5

Tags: fpga

Can I use pin B25 on PCI connector on my motherboard as a power supply or
I need to use pin B5 and B6 (5V) from PCI connector on motherboard and regulate it with AM1117 3.3V for my PCI board ?
I need the power supply for Cyclone II on my PCI board.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highly depends on your computer motherboard and power supply, as well as the specific FPGA (which you don't list) current demands.

That said, PCI is (according to both [Linear](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/design-note/dn346f.pdf) and [TI](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva002a/snva002a.pdf)) has a hotswap, power management requirement. The PCI port is disabled unless a PCI card is plugged in.

You could simply take the power straight off the power supply. Most ATX standards provide generous 3.3v and 5v lines, so you can power it off 3.3v or use a regulator on the beefier 5v rail.

Comment: The FPGA is cyclone II, EP2C8Q208CN

Answer (score 0):

Well depends on what you want to achieve. If you just want to get a clean 3.3V power,you should be able to take it from one of the many 3.3V power signals available from the connector. 
I believe it makes more sense to use a 3.3V from the PCI rather than creating your own power from the 5V, unless you need to have some very clean and very accurate voltage, which the AM1117 can not give you, then you should make it easier for yourself and take the power from the connector.

Comment: While the PCI standard is subscription only, a compliance checklist is available at http://www.pcisig.com/specifications/conventional/  This doc suggest that all 3.3V pins are bussed together for compliance.  Whether compliance is or isn't the goal here, taking 3.3V from the bussed pins seems the way to go.